# how to know user request goes to which server if we have multiple web front end servers

Tags: 2013

how to know user request goes to which server if we have multiple web front end servers 
we deployed asp.net application in iis 8.5 and users access this application from load balncer from out side the network this is internet based application.

Comment: Do you want to know which users are where, or only which WFE you're hitting with your request?

Comment: i need WFE the request hitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload a very small image file to

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`

Add the image to the page footer in one of your two WFEs. When you reload the page, you will either see the image, or not. And by that you know which is which since every WFE looks into its own image directory.

Reference: [Tip: How to determine which SharePoint web front end you’re hitting](http://geekswithblogs.net/kjones/archive/2010/10/29/142510.aspx)

Comment: any server side code can i use for display name of the server?

Comment: @adilahmed Add the server name in the image would do just fine